# When describing a CS paper, can it be assumed that the meaning of "tick" is known?

Tags: terminology

I thinkt this question fits better here than on english.stackexchange.

When describing a figure in a computer science paper, is it safe to use "tick" meaning "tick mark"?

Examples:
`... (see the thick line right of tick "17")`  meaning `tick mark "17"`
or `... increase at tick "1e+02"` `... increase at tick mark "1e+02"`.

Comment: If you have to ask...

Comment: "Tick mark"  would be less ambiguous.

Comment: "1e+02"? Seriously?-)

Comment: I change the my original values that make sense to bogus ones for the post. it's value larger than 400,000. Didn't check that 1e+02 dosen't make sense for the posting

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, if by tick you mean

[image].

No, if you mean

[image].

Comment: Actually I think he meant the tiny marks on the axes of a plot (Since his tick marks have got numbers).

Comment: My bad. I don't use graphs so often.

Comment: @Untitled I thought that was the irony of this answer :-)

Comment: It would be absolutely wonderful to read a CS paper that involved the latter tick.

Answer (score 10):

I've never heard those marks on the axes referred to as "ticks", though Wikipedia agrees with your usage.  Since Dave Clarke also didn't realise that's what you're talking about, I suspect that at least a sizeable minority of people aren't familiar with the term.

Why do you need to talk about the marks on the axes at all? Instead of saying "increase at tick mark '1e+02'" just say "increase at $x=100$" or whatever the variable is on that axis.  (Also, it's silly to use the notation "1e+02" for such a simple concept as 100.)  Your writing will be easier to understand if you talk about the data, rather than talking about the precise details of how you chose to represent it.